# How do I recreate this effect where UIcollectionview cells goes to the background when hitting the top

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, effect

I saw this demo and just can't get my mind off how to create this effect.

- Is it a UIcollectionview he uses?
- Is the effect some GitHub library or did he code it from scratch?

My big question is how this is done? Any hints what I can search for on google? I tried searching a lot of possible thing without luck. For example *"UIcollectionview effect", "Swift cell effect", "Swift passport effect", "Swift UIcollectionview library"* and so on...

Really hope some one can help my figure out this.

Here's the demo I saw:

[image]

Comment: I think its `UITableViewCell`. May be the animation done at `willDisplay ` & `didEndDisplaying ` methods

Comment: This tutorial does exactly what you want.  Check out the portion of the video called carousel view.
https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/65-custom-collection-view-layout/lessons/12?_ga=2.123976202.1271699087.1521202883-961121126.1453243640

Comment: Thanks!! I Will check it out later! Not sure if willDisplay and didEndDIsplaying will work as they only get fired once and I need to adjust size according to every finger position

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Can you make it as an answer? Then I will mark it answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonas,

An excellent example / tutorial of that behavior can be found on the RayWenderlich website.  Stack Overflow doesn't like links that leave this site as they might grow stale.  So simply visit that site and search for "Custom Collection View Layout".  Then visit the 12th lesson in the series.  It has a section called Carousel View that will guide you through creating something similar to what you have posted above.

Cheers!